# Detect words in quotation in a list

Tags: python

I have a list that corresponds to a question like this:

```
my_list = ["What", "language", "does", "the", "word", "«", "vibrato", "»", "come", "from", "?"]
```

And my program detects if there is a negation in this question (by detecting the words *"not", "don't"*...).

The problem is that it also detects these words when they are in a quotation, which is undesired e.g. if it's the name of a movie.

How can I detect negation words in my sentence only when they do not occur between quotation marks?

---

Example: suppose my list is:

```
my_list = ["who", "is", "not", "an", "animal", "?"]
```

It's a negative question but if I have:

```
my_list = ["who", "is", "James Bond", "in", "the", "movie", "«", "kill", "is", "not", "a", "game", "»", "?"]
```

It's not a negative question because the only negation is in a quote.

---

Currently, my program to detect negation is:

```
for words in my_list:
    for nword in negative_words:
        if words == nword:
            nega = True
            my_list.remove(words)
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

especially provide input, desired output and your attempt at coding a solution.

Comment: You could set a flag when you encounter an opening quote, and ignore all subsequent words until you encounter the closing quote.

Comment: I think the question is now quite clear, not sure if leaving it on hold is appropriate.

Comment: Seems like it's not going to get reopened, so [have a look](https://repl.it/repls/GranularThunderousResources) - documentation inside code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to see you improved your question and that it was reopened, so i can post an actual answer:

What you are missing is a flag which will tell you while parsing that a quote was being opened - and to remove it once the quote was closed so that you can continue for looking at negation words.

What happens really often after having developed this kind of script, a nested pattern will be encountered, which was not thought about beforehand - but this is not a problem since you can easily track multiple nested quotes. Now instead of working with a single flag, remember what character is expected to close the previously begun quote by adding it to a list - and only if that list is empty, try to find a negation word. Online demo for the following script: https://repl.it/repls/GranularThunderousResources

```
# What are the negation matchers
notwords = ("not", "don't", "doesn't", )

# What are the quoting pairs (opener, closer)
# The following logic can handle nested quotes, 
# so specify as many as you need without worrying
quotes = (("«", "»"), ("‹", "›"), ("<", ">"), )


# Needed for breaking out of outer loop when a
# starting quote was found
class StartingQuoteFound(Exception):
    pass


def is_negated(sentence):
    # Keep track of the expected quote closers
    closing_quotes = []
    for word in sentence:
        # Check if the current word is a quote opener
        try:
            for quote in quotes:
                if word == quote[0]:
                    # If found, remember that we await the quote 
                    # closer before considering a word match
                    # to a notword
                    closing_quotes.append(quote[1])
                    raise StartingQuoteFound()
        # Quote start was found, skip to the next word
        except StartingQuoteFound:
            continue

        # If we are waiting for quotes>0 to be closed
        if closing_quotes:
            # And it is the expected quote closer
            if closing_quotes[-1] == word:
                # Remove it from the quote closer expectations
                del closing_quotes[-1]
            # And go to the next word
            continue

        # Check if the word is within notwords
        # If found, we know that the sentence was negated
        if word in notwords:
            return True

    # No negation found
    return False

no_animal = ["who", "is", "not", "an", "animal", "?"]
print('expect negation:', is_negated(no_animal))

jon_is_kill = ["who", "is", "James Bond", "in", "the", "movie", "«", "kill", "is", "not", "a", "‹", "game", "›", "»", "?"]
print('not expect negation:', is_negated(jon_is_kill))

wat = ["James Bond", "in", "the", "movie", "«", "kill", "is", "not", "a", "‹", "game", "›", "»", "-", "doesn't", "drink", "alcohol"]
print('expect negation:', is_negated(wat))
```

Explanation for using an Exception when a starting quote was found: Python does not have labels which could be used to break/continue an outer loop, so you need to throw a specific exception and catch it within the outer loop, so that on encountering a starting quote it will move on with the parsing without further processing of that quote start.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag when you encounter an opening quote, and ignore all subsequent words until you encounter the closing quote:

```
flag_ignore = 0
negative_words = ["not", "don't"]
my_list = ["Do", "not", "say", "the", "word", "«", "don't", "»", "I", "don't", "like", "it"]
new_list = []

for word in my_list:
    if not flag_ignore and any(word.lower()==n for n in negative_words):
        pass
    else:
        new_list.append(word)

    if word == "«":
        flag_ignore = 1
    elif word == "»":
        flag_ignore = 0

print " ".join(new_list)
>>> "Do say the word « don't » I like it"
```